# What is this['string'](); in javascript and how it works;

Tags: javascript

I searched in google but i could not find anything

> test.js

```
class Hero(){
 heroVar = 'hero1'
 hero1() {
    alert('I am Hero 1');
 }
 onClick(){
    this[this.heroVar](); //this.heroVar value gets substituted with hero1
 }
}
```

Is there any better use case,how this **`this[this.heroVar]();`** works,please explain,
does this also adds **'.'** in between **'this'** and **'[]'** like `this.hero1()`

Comment: There are two ways to access a property of an object:  dot notation (`foo.bar`) and bracket notation (`foo[...]`, where `...` can be any expression). In this case the value that `this.heroVar` resolves to is used as property name for accessing `this`.

Comment: there is two ways of accessing a property in an object : . and [] By doing this this[] you will eval the value passed, so here you give a string which equals the function that you can directly execute. `this[this.heroVar]();` `this` = current object, `[]` accessing property/function, `this.heroVar` is a string which equal the name of your function, `()` you execute the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript class is an Object so

```
class Hero(){
 heroVar = 'hero1'
 hero1() {
    alert('I am Hero 1');
 }
 onClick(){
    this[this.heroVar](); //this.heroVar value gets substituted with hero1
    // equal with this['hero1']()
    // equal with hero1()
 }
}
```